# using includes in a hosts file

Tags: include, hosts

Can I do something similar to apache Include with my hosts file?

/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1    localhost
Include /something/test-hosts

/something/tests-hosts
127.0.0.1    test.local

Comment: Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60549/etc-hosts-file-refer-to-another-configuration-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to answer the question, no you cant use include in a hosts file